# Сложность с подключение MirPay на сайт

Tags: jwt, token

На нашей платежной форме реализовываем метод оплаты инвойсов через MirPay. Чтобы оплата прошла необходимо достать личный JWE-токен из приложения MirPay. Как это можно сделать? Вообще вопрос скорее теоретический - реально ли достать какие-либо данные на сайт из приложения на телефоне?